# Сравнение строк в массивах JS

Tags: javascript, строки

Вопрос такой, следующий скрипт:

```js
str1 = "test";
str2 = "test";
console.log(str1==str2); //true
```

Работает верно.
Но если я пытаюсь сравнить строки из массивов, то они никак не хотят сравниваться, как бы я их не преобразовывал в строку:

```js
fAfter[0]['Name'] = String("test");
fBefore[1]['Name'] = String("test");
console.log(fAfter[0]['Name']); //test
console.log(fBefore[1]['Name']); //test
console.log(typeof (fAfter[0]['Name'])) //string
console.log(typeof (fBefore[1]['Name'])) //string
console.log(fAfter[1]['Name'].toString() === fBefore[0]['Name'].toString()); //false
```

В чем тут подвох?

Comment: А добавьте инициализацию этих массивов.

Comment: У вас перепутаны индексы местами. Вместо `console.log(fAfter[1]['Name'].toString() === fBefore[0]['Name'].toString());` надо `console.log(fAfter[0]['Name'].toString() === fBefore[1]['Name'].toString());`